# How to filter elements based on type(<select>)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of elements, I want to filter it based on a condition which is all elements which are  type.

Eg.

```
$('.container').children('type[:select]')
```

I know above code is invalid but I want something like that, I want all elements with  type.

Pardon my js code, still newbie !

Comment: `$('container').find('select')`

Comment: looking for this one http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/ ?

Comment: Read the documentation on selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost exactly what you used, except `select` is an element

```
var $selects = $('.container').children('select');
```

or

```
var $selects = $('.container').find('select');
```

And the difference between the 2 is:

> the .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

<sup>From: [`jQuery.children` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/)</sup>

You can also do this entirely in 1 selector - for direct descendents (akin to `children` above)

```
var $selects = $('.container > select');
```

or for any descendent

```
var $selects = $('.container select');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('container').find('select')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type like `select` but it `select` is an html element:

```
$('.container').children('select')
$('.container > select')
```

---

> *I want all elements with type*

This confuses me. May be you want to get all the elements which has `type` attribute:

```
$('.container').children('[type]') // if direct child
```

use `.find()`:

```
$('.container').find('[type]') // if not a direct child
```